# I always thought that bodies of water were ground

Tags: voltage, ground

I always thought that bodies of water were ground, meaning that any electric voltage that meets a lake for example would be immediately become grounded and the voltage would be that of the earth, in other words zero. I'm thinking of times when lightening strikes a lake and people nearby in the lake get electrocuted. I have two questions.

1. Why do people get electrocuted if the lake is ground?
2. Even if the lake is not ground, where is the current flowing to so that it flows through a person's body thereby electrocuting him?

Comment: It is science not magic. The potential of the water, when no current is flowing is somewhere around the same as ground. But when a lightning strike hits, it creates a voltage gradient in the water as long as the strike continues. Anything with extent along that gradient will feel a voltage, and may conduct current.

Comment: So correct me if I'm wrong. 1. You're saying that the lake is not really ground. 2. If you're facing the lightening strike, then the voltage in front of you is greater than the voltage behind you making for a potential difference and that will create a current that flows from in front of you to the back of you.

Comment: Pretty much, yes. I mean, the ideal ground you are thinking of, which can conduct infinite current without any voltage rise, that ground does not exist. So I wouldn't say that the lake is "not really ground." And I cannot vouch for the polarity of lightning strikes. In other words, when facing the lightning, the voltage might be higher behind you or lower. But the point is that there is a voltage gradient in the water. Same thing applies to earth, for that matter. Lightning strikes create a voltage gradient in earth also.

Answer (score 4):

Water (not distilled) is an OK conductor, but not a great one. If lightning hits in one part of a lake and is conducted to another, the voltage drop across (for instance) 1 meter of water will follow the classic $$V = iR $$. where R is the resistance along a 1 meter path. For drinking water, this is on the order of 20 to 200 ohms/meter, while sea water will have something like 0.2 ohms per meter. Let's strike a balance of about 10 ohms/meter for fresh water.

So how much current is found in a lightning strike? Generally, in the range of 5,000 to 50,000 amps. Obviously this will not be concentrated in a small volume of water, or the water would flash into steam, but 10s to hundreds of amps is a good first estimate. Keep in mind that when lightning hits sand the discharge channel can melt the sand to glass, called fulgurites. Even 10 amps through 200 ohms/meter will produce a voltage differential of 2,000 volts along the length of a  2-meter tall person in the water, and since this is obviously well-coupled to the skin (the person is IN the water, after all), it should be clear that there is lots of potential (pun intended) for problems.

Comment: Yes I understand that non distilled water is an OK conductor. But why isn't it grounded when lightening strikes a lake since the water is touching the earth? In other words, why doesn't the water act as a lightening rod does and ground the lightening? As far as my second question goes, to where is the current flowing in the lake? In a plain circuit the current flows from + to -. Where is the negative in a lake that the current is flowing to?

Comment: @ArtS - it does, but as the current travels is produces a voltage difference. Since currents are high, so are the voltages. Water is not a superconductor. The "negative" you're thinking of is the entire local area which has contributed charge to the lightning strike. Where do you think that charge came from?

Answer (score 2):

On the scale of a lightning strike, the concept of DC 'ground' doesn't apply due to the high speed and large currents in the strike. Thus, the transient voltage across the space of a person (about a meter) can still be very high.

To answer your questions, combined: the lake itself can't be considered 'ground' during a lightning strike, where electricity is flowing along the paths of least resistance. The human body is essentially salt water, which would be more conductive than the surrounding fresh water of the lake. There is considerable charge transfer around and in a lightning strike over a short period of time. Thus, some of the considerable current due to the lightning strike would prefer to flow through the person.

Comment: This is the answer. I'm VERY, Very 1000 Verys familiar with Ohm's Law, Kirchoff's Laws etc. My misunderstanding was that lakes or pools are not really ground. And since they are not ground they have resistance and therefore current flows in the path of least resistance. Most of you (with my thanks though) merely gave me examples of people or animals being electrocuted. I wanted to know why.

Comment: Glad to help! If this answer is the most helpful, please add it as the accepted answer.

Answer (score 2):

In short... Not all grounds are equal.

What needs to be considered here is the path the current wants to flow to complete the electrical circuit.  Once you consider everything has an impedance a preferred return path may become apparent.

There is a very famous incident in the UK (august 2011) at Newbury horseracing.

A fault occurred somewhere and "high voltage" was present on the sodden ground. The stride length of a horse was enough such that the current preferred to go via the horse... "stride voltage"

In light of this, first aid at work now advocates an 18m radius around downed high voltage overhead lines. UK builders are advised to "bunny hop" away from an area where there is a downed overhead line to minimize their stride length while vacating the area.

https://www.beva.org.uk/_uploads/documents/august-2011-newsletter.pdf

Answer (score 1):

> Even if the lake is not ground, where is the current flowing to so that it flows through a person's body thereby electrocuting him?

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fam09G.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

*Figure 1. Lightning, water and Earth.*

The sketch may help. You have to consider the *whole* of Earth as being ground. Because the earth and water have resistance you can get local variation between locations if high currents flow between them. This can occur in lighting but also in major power faults where current returns to the distribution sub-station through the ground.

In my sketch the resistors signify the water resistance and ground resistance and the earth symbols represent Earth. It should be clear that when a very large current flows through the water that some potential (voltage) gradient will appear across it and similarly across the ground. It may help to think of a series of concentric circles with the highest voltage in the centre and decreasing voltage as you move further from this point.

> Why do people get electrocuted if the lake is ground?

If the extremities of the body are on different equi-potential lines then a current will flow through the body.

A similar risk exists when machinery comes in contact with overhead lines. The machine is live and, since it is generally steel, all points on it are at the cable voltage. If the operator climbs out of the machine and contacts ground while touching the machine s/he is in danger of electrocution. Best method would be to jump, land on one foot and hop out of the danger zone. Easier said than done.